# Android CursorLoader with multiple Contacts._IDs

Tags: android

I need to load my cursor with several Contacts using their unique _ID's. I can get a list of all Contacts but I'm having trouble with the SELECTION parameter of the CursorLoader.

What I have so far is :

```
private static final String SELECTION = Contacts._ID + " IN (?)";

public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    Uri contentUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

    String selection[] = new String[1]; 
    selection[0] = "8,50";

    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), contentUri, PROJECTION,
            SELECTION, selection, null);
}
```

This return no rows. If I change the selection array to just

```
selection[0] = "8"
```

then it correctly returns the contact with an _ID of 8.

Anyone have any ideas on how to retrieve multiple contacts using their _ID's?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `id in (?,?)` for selection for 2 items, if you have multiple `IDs` to select you have to put `(?,?,..)` as much as your count of selection items. Then give list of `IDs` in `selectionArgs[]` array like below:

```
String[] projection =...
String selectionArgs[] = {"8","50"};

String selection = Contacts._ID + " in (";
for (int i = 0; i < selectionArgs.length; i++) {
selection += "?, ";
}
selection = selection.substring(0, selection.length() - 2) + ")";
return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), contentUri, projection,
            selection, selectionArgs, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick test and found this sql statement works for me:

```
String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ) AND ("
                + Contacts._ID + " in (369, 330)))";
```

Code snippet here:

```
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        // This is called when a new Loader needs to be created.  This
        // sample only has one Loader, so we don't care about the ID.
        // First, pick the base URI to use depending on whether we are
        // currently filtering.
        Uri baseUri;
        if (mCurFilter != null) {
            baseUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
                    Uri.encode(mCurFilter));
        } else {
            baseUri = Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        }

        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ) AND (" 
                + Contacts._ID + " in (369, 330)))";
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, null,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
    }
```

For another option you was using, I tested it also. If you do want to use selectParameters, put it in this way:

```
        // Now create and return a CursorLoader that will take care of
        // creating a Cursor for the data being displayed.
        String select = "((" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " NOTNULL) AND ("
                + Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + "=1) AND ("
                + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " != '' ) AND (" 
                + Contacts._ID + " in (?,?)))";

        String selectionParams[] = new String[2]; 
        selectionParams[0] = "369";
        selectionParams[1] = "330";

        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri,
                CONTACTS_SUMMARY_PROJECTION, select, selectionParams,
                Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC");
```

Hopefully, this will help you.